# How to make tab layout in HTML

Tags: php, html

I need to make tabbed layout using HTML in my php page. Lets say welcome.php and all I need to show my page at the beginning as follows,

[image]

I need to make three tabs as below and each of this tab should be clickable. For details1 and details2, when I clicked that button it should popup a vertical menu.

[image]

Then I need the nature as follows,
When someone clicked Mainview, content should be displayed in the white space. If someone clicked Deatils1 then popup the menu if someone clicked item1 the content inside item1 should be show in whitespace likewise I need to navigate the content.

I have tried upto this level.Here is my try.

```
<?php
session_start();
 
// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./project/styles.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  


    
</head>


<div class="wrapper">
     
  <div class="sidebar">
    <h2 style="font-family: Verdana;">Dashboard</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i> Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Page 3</a></li>
         <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plug"></i> Page 4</a></li>
         <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Page 5</a></li>>
                 
    </ul> 
    
  </div>
    <div class="main_content">
    <?php
            include "adminHeader.php";       
     ?>

        <div class="info">

          
        </div>
        
          
      </div>
    </div>



</div>
```

From above code I could get Side bar and Admin Header as below,

[image]

can someone help me to achieve what I need? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Here is my current css styles,

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap');

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

body{
   background-color: #f3f5f9;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.wrapper .sidebar{
  width: 220px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #4b4276;
  padding: 30px 0px;
  position: fixed;
  
  font-size: 15px;

  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  
}

.wrapper .sidebar h2{
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li{
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bdb8d7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}    

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a{
  color: #bdb8d7;
  display: block;
  
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a .fas{
  width: 25px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover{
  background-color: #594f8d;
}
    
.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover a{
  color: #fff;
}
 
.wrapper .sidebar .social_media{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .social_media a{
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  background: #594f8d;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 5px;
  color: #bdb8d7;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.wrapper .main_content{

  margin-left: 220px;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  display: block ;
  
}

.hidden{
  display :none;
  }

.wrapper .main_content .header{
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #717171;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e4e8;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  width: 100% ;
    
}




 

.wrapper .main_content .info{
  margin: 10px;
  color: #717171;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.wrapper .main_content .info div{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.error {
    color: red;
}
.vega-actions {display: none}

h3 { 
font-family: 'Source Code Pro', sans-serif;
font-weight: 50;
font-size: 10px;
margin-top:0px;
display: block;
color: #404040;
text-align: right;
border-top:3px solid #000;

}


.main_content .info .card .card-body h3 { 
  
  font-size: 15px;
  
  
  }


.card {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
  }


  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
 }


 .yellowBg {
  background-color: #0ff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick overview of what you want trying to achieve. Just check and run the code below. Hope it gives you idea.

```js
document.querySelector(".has-sub").onclick = function() {
    children = this.children[1];
  if ( children.classList.contains("open") ) {
    children.classList.remove("open");
    } else {
    children.classList.add("open");
  }
}
```

```css
.has-sub,
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.has-sub,
.nav-menu {
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}

.has-sub {

  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.sub {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: none;
     background: gray;
}

.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav-menu">
    <a href="#">
      main view
    </a>
   </div>
  <div class="has-sub">
    <span>detail 1</span>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li>sub detail 1</li>
      <li>sub detail 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-menu">
    <a href="#">
      detail 2
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanx! but when I use this same code, I could see mainview at the center and deail2 at the next line.

Comment: ah, maybe something conflict in you default css styles. I just quick add some css on it thou. Just try to rewrite the code again same as what I have posted. Just get the idea on it.

Comment: If its is working and solve your problem now. Kindly accept my answer that would be appreciated.

Comment: I have updated my css styles. I could still see it on the center